# Why the th:value is empty if th:text is working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So I have this in my html:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 
<body>
        <form th:action="@{/user/set-new-password}" method="post">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="password" name="matchesPassword" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${token}" th:text="${token}">
            <input type="submit" class="submit-button" th:value="#{changePassword.submitButton}"/>              
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/set-new-password")
public String changePasswordForm(Model model, @ModelAttribute("token") String token) {
    model.addAttribute("token", token);

    return "relatedToUserAccounts/change-password";
}
```

The HTML is looking like this

```
<input type="hidden" value=""></input>
```

I want to look like this if the token = "abcd1234"

```
<input type="hidden" value="abcd1234"></input>
```

For the th:text it's working and the html shows the text, but the th:value stays empty.

Comment: I miss the `<input name` as also hidden inputs should have a name. And `th:field="..."` might be a thought, though I have no experience with thymeleaf.

Comment: the <input name="token" does not change anything. Also the th:field="..." has no effect... the result is like this with th:field: <input type="hidden" name="" id="" value=""> --> still empty

Comment: `th:text` on an input doesn't make sense. An `input` is an empty element that can't contain any text. If `th:value="${token}"` doesn't work it means that `token` is most likely empty. Does `<p th:text="${token}"></p>` display anything? If not, then `token` isn't set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `th:text`, instead use `name="token"` and `th:value="${token}"`

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="token" th:value="${token}"> --> <input type="hidden" name="token" value="">